# Run Ruby script that is stored on internet

Tags: ruby

I have my hosting and domain where I uploaded my Ruby script. I was running local scripts using this command: `ruby path/to/script/script.rb`. I uploaded my Ruby script and I want to run it in my terminal like this: `ruby http://www.example.com/script.rb` but it doesn't work. How do I do this properly? Can I do it with curl+ruby?

Please note that this is not website, web app or anything such. It's just a Ruby script that can be opened in terminal and do some stuff.

Comment: What r you using to serve the https request?

Comment: @OK9999 First of all its `http` and I am using `ruby` command to open file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run the ruby program located on website, you can try:

```
curl -s http://wwww.example.com/script.rb | ruby
```

`-s` option to curl is for silent mode so that there is no additional output from curl command.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is built into ruby (i could be wrong), so what you will have to do is create a small ruby script that fetches whatever from whatever URL is on the command line, then evaluates it (using eval).

If are not on Windows u can use a script like this, which you can build on.  I.e. make it so the URL is a cmd line param.  Alternatively you could just run this from the command line:

```
require 'net/http'

eval(Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse("http://127.0.0.1:8000/test_script.rb")).body)
```

Comment: Well I am on Linux so this doesn't help :|

Comment: I guess I was not clear.  The script will run fine anywhere u have a ruby.

Comment: That is the way to do this, or maybe using chef but that only its configuration script.